# Need to prohibit writing CD/DVD for all non-admin users in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, system-settings, preferences

We have a requirement that forbids users writing to removable media such as CDs.  So far all I've been able to find is

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitBurn true
```

but that is a per-user setting that can be reversed by the user and doesn't prevent them from writing with an app other than finder.

Is it possible to take user level preferences from ~/Library and put them in /Library such that they override a value the user might later try to set?  This way I can at least prevent them using finder to burn media.

Secondly, is there any global method of preventing any write access to the cdrom device?

Comment: Did you look the parental controls. They're able to disable burning and it's probably possible to enable it to every non admin users.

Comment: Users are authenticated by Active Directory, and parental controls only work on local users.